Why is auto smoothing and shade smoothing not working and what can I do to correct the vertices?
Odd distortion is found on model. I believe it is a vertices problem but I'm not too sure. Autosmoothing is not working and neither is shade smoothing. This is an fbx model. I am using blender 4.2. 

Without the file I can only make educated guesses. It looks as if the geometry is quite messy, so probably you have duplicate vertices, edges or faces there, eventually flipped normals, or custom split normals. But most likely a combination of all these causes.

Hello. Booleans notoriously produce ugly geomtry. You need to create edge loops under the holes so the shading is cleaner. There are a bunch of examples on this site. Cheers
